# Insufficient Privileges in Email Body pane on contact Activity Email

Tags: email, ui, insufficient-privileges, activity

My client has a weird bug where they can see the whole tab for Email in the Activity Tab on the Contact page, but the rich text editor for entering the body of the email shows an Insufficient Privileges error.

[image: Insufficient Privileges on Rich Text Editor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hgolov I'm running into this exact issue. Here are a few additional things that I've noticed, which may/may not be relevant:

1. As admin user, the user is not able to edit the HTML body portion of an email template record, when going straight to the email template record.
2. This is is a trial org (contract signed, awaiting end of trial period).

Privileges granted to profile including "Edit HTML Templates", "Send Email through External Email Service", "Manage Public Lightning Email Templates", "Send Email", "Mass Email", "Create Folders for Lightning Email Templates".

If you have any luck figuring this one out, I'd be very interested to hear what you discover.

Comment: Hi @mountainrog - this just resolved itself for my user. Sorry!